# Android ListView OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-listview, onclicklistener, listviewitem

I need to add a code responsible for action when one row from my list is clicked. I don't know if it should be `OnItemClickListener` or `OnClickListener` and how&where to write it. My app is with view holder. Here is my code:

```
 public class JobListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public static class WorkViewHolder {
        public TextView mJob;
        public ImageView mImageAndroKorpo;
    }
    public JobListAdapter(Context mContext, List<String> mDane) {
        super(mContext, R.layout.list_element_job, mDane);
        this.mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        WorkViewHolder mHolder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_element_job, parent, false);
            mHolder = new WorkViewHolder();

            TextView mJobsName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nazwa_oferty);
            ImageView mImageAndroKorpo = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

            mHolder.mJob = mJobsName;
            mHolder.mImageAndroKorpo = mImageAndroKorpo;

            convertView.setTag(mHolder);
        } else {
            mHolder = (WorkViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        final String mWorkPosition = getItem(position); 

        mHolder.mJob.setText(mWorkPosition);
        mHolder.mJob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Here?
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I added code where I think it should be placed. Is it ok? OnItem or OnClick? And how to use item position?

My list_element_job.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="10dp"

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/list_checkbox"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:src="@drawable/android_white_piece"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:background="@drawable/android_korpo_transparent3"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textSize="7pt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nazwa_oferty"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Details..."
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/nazwa_oferty"
        android:textSize="6pt"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me somehow :)

Comment: add onItemClickListener in your Activity class to ListView

Comment: remove onClickListener from getview() method for adapter class and add listview.setonItemClick in Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `onClick` from your adapter class. And add `OnItemClickListener` to your `ListView`

example:

```
JobListAdapter jobListAdapter = new JobListAdapter (...);
listView.setAdapter(jobListAdapter);

listView..setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, and how can I pass an index of selected row to next activity? My project includes custom adapter and view holder... if that changes anything.

Comment: `int position` is a index, that you can pass to next activity using `Intent`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the focus for the checkbox in xml like below:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/list_checkbox"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

because of check box focus list item click listeners wont work.